# SQL: Multi Table, One to Many, Multi Sum query

Tags: sql, sum, hierarchy, multi-level

I'm trying to grab data from multiple tables and do some summing.  The data structure is like this:

TransHeader

- TranDate
- TranNbr
- Units

TransDetail

- TranNbr
- TranWeight
- TranTime

There are multiple TransDetail records for each TransHeader.

There is a ton of data, so I'm trying to summarize to get output like the following:

Date, Total Units, Total Weight, Total Time

where each line would represent the totals by date.

Here's my unsuccessful attempt:

```
select th.TranDate, sum(th.Units), sum(td.TranWeight), sum(td.TranTime)
from TransHeader th join
     TransDetail td
     on td.TranNbr = th.TranNbr
group by th.TranDate;
```

It works fine for the TranWeight and TranTime, but the Units comes out over inflated because it sums the units for each hit on the TransDetail table.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because you are aggregating along a hierarchy.  Perhaps the simplest method is two levels of aggregation:

```
select th.TranDate, sum(th.Units), sum(td.TranWeight), sum(td.TranTime)
from TransHeader th join
     (select td.TranNbr, sum(td.TranWeight) as TranWeight, sum(td.TranTime) as TranTime
      from TransDetail td
      group by td.TranNbr
     ) td
     on td.TranNbr = th.TranNbr
group by th.TranDate;
```